# How to get a valid access token for a GCP account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-iam

I want to get a list of intents via the Dialogflow API. I send a GET request to this URL https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/my_project_id/agent/entityTypes. And for the Bearer token I use the result of the following command: `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`. But I get such error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "IAM permission 'dialogflow.entityTypes.list' on 'projects/my_project_id/agent' denied.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}}
```

Then, I opened this [APIs explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/dialogflow/v2/dialogflow.projects.getAgent), sent request, and just extract a token from the Authorization header 
[click to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idhdh.png)
And this is a valid token. But, unfortunately, it expires every 20 minutes. So, my question is why does `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` return the wrong token, and how can I get a token permanently?
I have these roles:

- Dialogflow API Client
- Dialogflow API Reader
- Editor

Comment: You may want to check the role/s assigned to the service account whether it has the necessary DialogFlow permissions

Comment: Example: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup

Comment: This is not a service account. I do it with my account. And I have the necessary roles. I updated my question

Comment: You should use a service account then, and generate a service account key file as indicated in the example in my previous comment

Comment: You are using the wrong CLI command. Use `gcloud auth print-access-token`. This command generates an OAuth Access Token. All Google OAuth tokens expire. You will need to learn how to program using Service Accounts. Lots of examples on the Internet. Google has good documentation on this subject.